# NullPointerException (@PhoneWindow:onKeyUpPanel:1002) {main}

Tags: java, android

I get strange exceptions in my analytics lately.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:1002)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1703)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2114)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3626)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3596)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2839)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4904)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am missing a lead on what I can do to prevent this.

Comment: Looks like a bug in support library on LG devices https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78154

Comment: thanks - this is the info i needed - somehow your google-kung-fu is better than mine ;-)

Comment: BTW how did you guys know it's LG device bug?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Until LG fixes this issue (which could be months, depending on how long it takes them to release new firmware), the following workaround worked for me. Just add the following code to your `Activity` class:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && "LGE".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.BRAND)) {
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && "LGE".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.BRAND)) {
       openOptionsMenu();
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This the better answer

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a bug in support library on LG devices https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78154

Answer (score 0):

We implemented a variant of Alex's answer. Since the bug only appears on 4.1 devices, we prefer not to override anything in later versions:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return mightCrash(keyCode) || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {
    if (mightCrash(keyCode)) {
        openOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

/**
 * See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78154
 */
private boolean mightCrash(int keyCode) {
    return keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && "LGE".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.BRAND) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN;
}
```