# Overflow Menu doesn't work on Appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, overflow-menu

I have just moved from Eclipse to Android Studio, and I am using the Appcompat library because it comes by default in Android Studio and it is hard to deactivate it.

The problem is that when I create a ActiveBar, the items that should be shown in the Overflow menu, never appear, neither the overflow menu icon (3 dots).

Only the items in the bar are created, and if I touch the hardware key for opening the overflow menu, the app crushes.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.learning.app1.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

main_activity_actions:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Logcat:

```
01-24 02:48:18.111  14717-14717/com.learning.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412fa438)
01-24 02:48:18.131  14717-14717/com.learning.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:986)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2098)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3621)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3591)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2834)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4905)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I used the Blank Activity that comes with Android Studio, and only modified the main_activity_actions XML file. I don't know if did I something wrong or if the Appcompat library has a bug.

Please if you could help me I would be gratefull. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your crash log.

Comment: If you are running the app on a LG device, look at [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833242/nullpointerexception-phonewindowonkeyuppanel1002-main

Comment: Yes, I am running it on an LG device, it seems like a bug in the LG firmware. Anyway the solution posted there worked for me.Post your comment as an answer so that I can check this question as answered.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common issue on LG devices. Look at link in my comment.