# Null Pointer on onKeyUpPanel?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I just had the following crash reported to me, and I don't even have the slightest clue what if anything I can do to resolve the question. The reported Android version was 4.1, the device is a LG Optimus G. Any ideas as to what I can do? Note that no one line is my code, it's all internal Android stuff, I'm not even sure how it got reported to me...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:986)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2098)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3621)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3591)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2834)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4905)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a known LG issue. To resolve, [add the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27024610/544198), which will work around the LG bug:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && "LGE".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.BRAND)) {
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && "LGE".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.BRAND)) {
       openOptionsMenu();
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```